# How to deal with different lengths of dependent variables for Multiple Multivariate regression?

Tags: r, multivariate-regression

So this question is probably part statistics and part r studio related. I want to run a Multiple Multivariate Regression with 13 dependent variables and 4 predictors. The 13 variables are scales from 1-6, which I coded as a numeric variable. Unfortunately, some of these variables don't show the full range, therefore have different lengths.

Question 1: I believe I read somewhere, that this poses a problem for the calculations and should therefore be addressed. Is that true for this type of code? And what about the predictors and their ranges?

Question 2: If it does pose a problem in interpreting results, how can I fix this? Is it enough to standardize the dependent variables maybe? How do I do this in R though?

(As an example I am using the Quartet data set from R, just rounding each variable)

```
Quartet

Quartet$y1 <- round(Quartet$y1, 0)
Quartet$y2 <- round(Quartet$y2, 0)
Quartet$y3 <- round(Quartet$y3, 0)
Quartet$y4 <- round(Quartet$y4, 0)

summary(Quartet)


M <- lm(cbind(y3, y4) ~ x + x4, data = Quartet)

summary(M)
```

Keep in mind, this code runs smoothly without an error, that isn't the issue. I would need to do extra diagnostic checking at this point. But I don't know just in how far the results are rigged just by having different ranges for y3 (5-12) and y4 (5-13).

Thank you!

(I moved this question here from stack overflow, because it was suggested there.)

Comment: What do you mean that they have different lengths?

Answer (score 0):

Not really what your question asks, but I feel its obligatory to mention that it can be problematic to model likert-type scale data as continuous and linear (which is what a linear regression is doing here). If you wanted to be more true to the data generating process then I would suggest an ordered logistic regression.

Now to your original question, assuming we're going to stick with a linear regression framework and acknowledge the limitations, one option might be to mean center and standardize all of your DV's and then interpret them as as such. There's probably other (better) approaches, but this was the first that came to mind for me.

Comment: If I would use the ordered logistic regression for this model, would there be any additional conditions for model fitting? I am finding resources on how to run it in R, just no mention of any testing for accuracy. 
I am going to try both ways though, thank you